# Powershell process timeouts in Kudu

Tags: azure, powershell, kudu

I'm trying to run this PS script in Azure Kudu diagnostic console, Process is terminated around in 58 mins. Anyone know why?

I already researched on the Kudu code, and couldn't find any limitation with kudu.

```
$count = 3600 + 120;
$index = 0;
Write-Output "Starting timeout test. Test will run for $count seconds."
while ($count -gt $index) {
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
  $index = $index + 1;
  Write-Output "$index seconds passed now ..."
}
Write-Output "Completed without timeout after $index seconds!"
```

[image: Debug Console Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as intended,

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/blob/master/Kudu.Services/Commands/PersistentCommandController.cs#L322-L326

However this is not documented yet, So left a bug in the kudu git to fix the documentation
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/3025

Answer (score 0):

By default, the SCM timeout is 20 minutes. But you can increase it by setting: `**WEBSITE_SCM_IDLE_TIMEOUT_IN_MINUTES=30**`

Note that this is not needed if you are also using the Always On feature.

Check this thread : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3212de5b-efd2-4c49-a247-6bc6af5c68e8/running-a-task-in-kudu-cmdpowershell-console-terminates-the-console-process?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Comment: SCM Idle timeout will not impact this script as it does output and also there is CPU operation, SCM Idle timeout will only occur when you don't have output or CPU operation

Comment: Thank you, Mohit Verma.